# Неявный принцип работы AutoResetEvent

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Столкнулся с непонятным поведением механизма AutoResetEvent.

Есть следующих код:

```
static void Main()
{
    new Thread(Method1).Start();
    new Thread(Method2).Start();

    Thread.Sleep(500);

    Console.WriteLine("нажмите любую клавишу");
    Console.ReadKey();
    auto.Set();            
    auto.Set(); 

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

к нему есть пара методов:

```
static void Method1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Метод 1 запущен");
    auto.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine("Метод 1 остановлен");
}

static void Method2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Метод 2 запущен");
    auto.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine("Метод 2 остановлен");
}
```

Судя по описанию AutoResetEvent, метод Set() должен отправлять сигнал только одному потоку, т.е. каждый вызов метода Set() будит один из двух запущенных методов. Соответственно отработать должны оба. 
Но в данном случае до конца отрабатывает только один из методов, программа при этом зависает. С чем может быть связано такое поведение?

-------------^^UPD
При запуске через f11 всё отрабатывает, однако проблема не решена

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас классическая «гонка» потоков. В вашем случае второй `Set` успевает отработать до того, как один из потоков проснётся, и `auto` будет сброшен в исходное состояние. У `AutoResetEvent`, в отличие от семафора, нету счётчика взведений, а только внутренний флаг «взведён/нет». В результате вы его взводите два раза подряд, он остаётся взведённым, а рабочий поток просыпается позже, сбрасывает его, а снова взвести уже некому.

Вам нужно завести для синхронизации *ещё один* `AutoResetEvent`, который бы сообщал «привет, я проснулся!», устанавливать его в рабочих потоках, и дожидаться между вызовами `Set`.

Comment: Да, добавление задержки между первым и вторым Set решило проблему. Спасибо

Comment: @Garrus_En: Пожалуйста!